# Must declare scalar variable "@.." gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to update a row in my gridview, but not the whole row just the forename and surname values

but Im getting the above error i'm adding my values from code behind and they are all defined.  The error occurs during runtime in the console

here is my code

code behind:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox updateForeName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtForename");

            TextBox updateSurName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtSurname");


          //  string contactID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            string contactID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

           SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["ContactID"].DefaultValue = contactID;

            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Forename"].DefaultValue = updateForeName.Text;
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Surname"].DefaultValue = updateSurName.Text;
            SqlDataSource1.Update();
}
```

Update Command from SQLdatasource:

```
   UPDATE tblcontact
SET          Forename = @Forename, Surname = @Surname
WHERE  (ContactID = @ContactID)
```

Here is the a relevant snip of the gridview markup

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed targetFont" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RowStyle-Wrap="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                                DataKeyNames="ContactID" EmptyDataText="There is donation data to be displayed" OnLoad="GridView1_Load" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" SortExpression="ContactID" ReadOnly="false" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forename" SortExpression="Forename">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtForename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Forename") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblForename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Forename") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSurename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Business Name" HeaderText="Business Name" Visible="False" ></asp:BoundField>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="House Number" HeaderText="House Number" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AddressLine1" HeaderText="AddressLine1" SortExpression="AddressLine1" ></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AddressLine2" HeaderText="AddressLine2" SortExpression="AddressLine2" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False"></asp:BoundField>
```

SqlDataSource1 Markup

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AreaCollectionConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT tblcontact.ContactID, tblcontact.Forename, tblcontact.Surname, tbladdress.[House Number], tbladdress.AddressLine1, tbladdress.AddressLine2, tblcontact.[Business Name] FROM tblcontact INNER JOIN tbladdress ON tblcontact.AddressID = tbladdress.AddressID LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDonate ON tblcontact.ContactID = tblDonate.ContactID WHERE (tbladdress.CollectionArea = @CollectionArea) AND (tbladdress.AddressLine1 = @drpCollectionStreet) ORDER BY tbladdress.AddressLine1"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO tblDonate(DonationMonth, NoDonationReason, ContactID, DonationAmount, Date) VALUES (@DonationMonth, @NoDonationReason, @ContactID, @DonationAmount, @Date)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblcontact SET Forename = @Forename, Surname = @Surname WHERE (ContactID = @ContactID)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="DonationMonth" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NoDonationReason" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContactID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DonationAmount" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpCollectionAreaSelection" Name="CollectionArea" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpCollectionStreet" Name="drpCollectionStreet" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Forename" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Surname" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContactID" />


        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Im using the below elsewhere and it works fine

```
string donationMonth = (GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            string donationID = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string DonationAmount = (GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDonationAmount") as TextBox).Text;


            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["DonationMonth"].DefaultValue = donationMonth;
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["DonationAmount"].DefaultValue = DonationAmount;
            SqlDataSource2.Update();
```

Comment: See this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1024764.aspx?Programmatically+setting+UpdateParameters+for+a+SQLDataSource+control) which talks about a very similar problem

Comment: Could you show the declaration of your SqlDataSource1? Do you have it declared complete with the UpdateCommand and the UpdateParameters in your aspx markup?

Comment: I believe so see above

Comment: Andrei - I've done exactly as the document said and moved my code to sqldatasource updating event but still get the same error

Comment: I've just tried your exact update code along with gridview markup and it worked with no problem but I removed the select paramaters. Can you please debug and specify at which part of the code is the error occurring exactly? is it when calling .Update() method or after that?

Comment: The error actually occurs during runtime but I believe its during the update method here is the exact error from the debugger in the browser Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.

Must declare the scalar variable "@ContactID".

Comment: are you sure the sql select statement is returning all the columns specified by the right name? seems like an obvious question, but double check

Comment: and also try to rebuild your solution.

Comment: Tried rebuilding and Prospector I have checked and it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Would you please change and let me know if resolved;

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" SortExpression="ContactID" ReadOnly="false" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
```

To

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" SortExpression="ContactID" **ReadOnly="true"** Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
```